# Configure third party DNS to Static Public Ip attached to AWS ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

First at all, I am a beginner in this fields, so apologies If my questions is stupid or just too easy.

**What do we want to configure?** Well, we have a partnership with a website **wwww.partner.com**.

We have an application running on **elastic beanstal**k with an application load balancer. And we need to **provide** to our partner a **STATIC IP** for the to link **[www.partner.com/ourcarpet](http://www.partner.com/ourcarpet)** to it.

To sum up, we want this architecture:

**DNS - [www.partner.com/ourcarpet](http://www.partner.com/ourcarpet) -------> OUR STATIC IP IN AWS
STATIC IP IN AWS -----> NLB --> EB**

I created a Network Load Balancer, and attract to it a STATIC IP. What I do not know is how to access to this IP through HTTPS.

Am I using the correct approach? Can I link me Statis IP to a CNAME or A in a DNS outside of AWS?

Comment: An Application Load Balancer and a Network Load Balancer are not the same thing in AWS, they can have similar uses, but behave somewhat differently even if they both would be listening on port 443/tcp. In either case you should have a DNS name for the load balancer linked to your application and you can give that to your partner to be added as a CNAME record on their DNS domain, and that should be taken care of. It's not clear why you need a specific static IP address.

Comment: @OscarDeLeón yes, you are right. That was our first approach, but each time we rebuild the EB environment that DNS changes.  So our second approach was to have the subdomain inside of AWS. That's works but we still think the best is a sIP

Answer (score 0):

Here (https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/10/aws-alb-static-ips/) I found a post that solved our problem.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).